# How to do conditional on NCurses getEvent

Tags: haskell, ncurses

I'm looking at the info from here: [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ncurses-0.2.16/docs/UI-NCurses.html#g:14)

I want different things to happen in my program depending on which arrow-key was pressed. Using the NCurses module, I can register an event with the getEvent function. But I cannot get my if statements to work on the stored event. This is my code:

```
main = runCurses $ do
    w <- defaultWindow
    e <- getEvent w (Just 300)
    let x = setX e

setX e
    | e == KeyLeftArrow = -1
    | e == KeyRightArrow = 1
    | otherwise = 0
```

This gives `Couldn't match expected type ‘Key’ with actual type ‘Maybe Event’` So I change to `e == Just Key...Arrow` and then get

```
Couldn't match type ‘Event’ with ‘Key’
      Expected type: Maybe Key
        Actual type: Maybe Event
```

I guess this is because `e` is an Event, and I'm acting as if it were a Key, but even after trying this `Key e == Just Key...Arrow` it isn't working. How can I turn this event into a key? Or in some other way just be able to get my conditional on `e` to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [`getEvent`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ncurses-0.2.16/docs/UI-NCurses.html#v:getEvent) definition

```
getEvent
  :: Window  
  -> Maybe Integer  
  -> Curses (Maybe Event)
```

you may notice that it returns `Maybe Event` wrapped into `Curses` monad. And in `setX` function you are trying to compare event to key.
Compiler says you exactly about this mismatch:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Event’ with ‘Key’
  Expected type: Maybe Key
    Actual type: Maybe Event
```

Let's go to documentation and find a bit more about `Event` and `Key` types.
Here is how [`Event`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ncurses-0.2.16/docs/UI-NCurses.html#t:Event) is defined:

```
data Event
    = EventCharacter Char
    | EventSpecialKey Key
    | EventMouse Integer MouseState
    | EventResized
    | EventUnknown Integer
```

You may notice that `Event` has several variants (constructors) and one of them `EventSpecialKey` wraps `Key`. That is exactly what you need.

```
setX e
    | e == Just (EventSpecialKey KeyLeftArrow) = -1
    | e == Just (EventSpecialKey KeyRightArrow) = 1
    | otherwise = 0
```

Comment: Personally, I feel uneasy about using the `Eq` instance when we can just pattern-match on ADTs. Might be just me though?

Comment: yep, I also prefer `case .. of`. Your suggestion to use `LambdaCase` is even better. Just decided to make minimal changes to the original code.

Comment: Of course. Perhaps also worth mentioning for OPs benefit, a halfway house would be to write eg. ` | Just (EventSpecialKey KeyLeftArrow) <- e = -1` (using pattern guards and pattern matching but without `case`).

Answer (score 1):

Youve correctly identified the problem. Your proposed solution, to put `Key` on left hand side of the equals, is to *assert* that you have a key, when you've already identified that in fact you don't!

Looking at the package link reveals that an `Event` might be a keypress `EventSpecialKey Key`. Thus,

```
setX e = case e of --lambdacase would be even more idiomatic
    Just (EventSpecialKey KeyLeftArrow) -> -1
    Just (EventSpecialKey KeyRightArrow) -> 1
    _ -> 0
```